# Deploy via PM2 from private github repo

Tags: node.js, git, github, pm2

I'm using PM2 to deploy my apps, so far it worked great, however now that I have sensitive API credentials I made my repos private and now I'm unable to deploy via PM2. I have ssh set up and can successfully connect to github via

```
ssh git@github.com
```

Here is my ecosystem.json file used for deployment (which works when in public mode):

```
  "deploy" : {
    "production" : {
            "key" : "../.ssh/id_rsa.pem",
      "user" : "root",
      "host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "ref"  : "origin/master",
      "repo" : "git@github.com/AndreasGalster/productnews-graphql.git,
      "path" : "/var/www/production",
      "post-deploy" : "yarn install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production"
    }
  }
```

Is it not possible to deploy a private repository? If so, how should I do it? I always get "could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address" Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: Your `repo` key should be `git@github.com:AndreasGalster/productnews-graphql.git`

Comment: Sorry, my bad for the typo. I just changed it (and the missing quotes), it's not working though. I've tried pretty much any possible combination I can imagine already for hours.  The weird thing is it's saying can't read username for https:// ... shouldn't it reflect the url was defined in repo?

Comment: looks like an old question, can you share the way you solved the problem here?